# UnsatisfiedLinkError : setMessageHandler(Native Method)

Tags: android, unsatisfiedlinkerror

I am making an application in which I have used some native methods,and these methods are defined in a separate class. When I create the instance of that class in my Activity class then this type of error is occurs.

This is the my Activity Class

```
public class LoginActivity extends Activity
{
        PortSipSdk sdk;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.loginview);
        sdk = PortSipSdk.getInstance();//error is occurs at this line
        sdk.setOnRegisterListener(this);
    }
}
```

Java class is

```
public class PortSipSdk {
    private final String TAG = "PortSipSdk";
    private static PortSipSdk instance;
    private PortSipNetwork mNetAssist;
    private KeyguardLock mKeyguardLock;

    private Context mContext;

    long mSessionID = PortSipErrorcode.INVALID_SESSION_ID;

    public synchronized static PortSipSdk getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new PortSipSdk();            
        }
        return instance;
    }

    private PortSipSdk() {
        msgDispatcher = new MainHandler();
        setMessageHandler(msgDispatcher);
        videoRecorder = new PortSipVideoRecoder();
    }


    public native void setMessageHandler(Handler msghandler);

    // Initialize and register functions
    private native int initializeSDK(int enum_transport, String agent,
            String STUNServer, int STUNServerPort);
}
```

Log is

```
07-30 12:13:01.852: E/AndroidRuntime(651): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-30 12:13:01.852: E/AndroidRuntime(651): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: setMessageHandler
07-30 12:13:01.852: E/AndroidRuntime(651):  at com.portsip.PortSipSdk.setMessageHandler(Native Method)
07-30 12:13:01.852: E/AndroidRuntime(651):  at com.portsip.PortSipSdk.<init>(PortSipSdk.java:62)
07-30 12:13:01.852: E/AndroidRuntime(651):  at com.portsip.PortSipSdk.getInstance(PortSipSdk.java:55)
07-30 12:13:01.852: E/AndroidRuntime(651):  at com.portsip.test.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:48)
07-30 12:13:01.852: E/AndroidRuntime(651):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
07-30 12:13:01.852: E/AndroidRuntime(651):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
07-30 12:13:01.852: E/AndroidRuntime(651):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
07-30 12:13:01.852: E/AndroidRuntime(651):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
07-30 12:13:01.852: E/AndroidRuntime(651):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
07-30 12:13:01.852: E/AndroidRuntime(651):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-30 12:13:01.852: E/AndroidRuntime(651):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-30 12:13:01.852: E/AndroidRuntime(651):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
07-30 12:13:01.852: E/AndroidRuntime(651):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-30 12:13:01.852: E/AndroidRuntime(651):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
07-30 12:13:01.852: E/AndroidRuntime(651):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
07-30 12:13:01.852: E/AndroidRuntime(651):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
07-30 12:13:01.852: E/AndroidRuntime(651):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: remove syncronized keyword from getInstance method.

Comment: after removing syncronized keyword it not worked

Comment: did you load the native library?

Comment: No...problem is that you have declared as a static and in activity you have make object for that class..so remove static keyword also.

Comment: @blackbelt yes native library has been loaded

Comment: @ShaniGoriwal removing static has made some new error come up which may take few minutes to resolve.

Comment: @amardeep with the context you provide is impossible to understa what's going on. you could have missplelled , or the paramters or the package are inconsisten

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your NDK binary is in your APK.